# Delete camera files automatically on FTP

Tags: server, ftp, camera, cron

I have 4 IP cameras which are save records on FTP.
Lets call FTP ftp://serwer.ftp.com/records/ (5GB limit)

Each camera is create their own folder

```
Camera A ftp://serwer.ftp.com/records/A/
Camera B ftp://serwer.ftp.com/records/B/
Camera C ftp://serwer.ftp.com/records/C/
Camera D ftp://serwer.ftp.com/records/D/
```

How to remove files from FTP older than 2 weeks for each camera ?

Can you please help me to create CRON job for that or is there any other way ?

Comment: How do the filenames look? Can you provide a sample long listing? Can you control the format of the filenames?

Comment: The sample file name is: MDalarm_20170707_090851.mkv. I am not able to change the name is camera system.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly 4 years and no answer? Assuming you have a *nix like system with shell access, just run:

```
find /path/to/ftpd/dir -mtime +14 -delete
```

That will delete everything older than 14 days and nights from the current time. Make sure your clock is correct! `-mmin +100` would be anything over 100 minutes old.

You can also store files on a flash drive with a hard drive that is spun down, and every night the directories that are more than 2 days old get moved to the mechanical hard drive. Something like

```
find /path/to/date_directories -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +2 -exec mv -t /mnt/big_storage/camera/ \{\} \;
```

This assumes that the camera creates a new directory every midnight.

Comment: Why would someone spend the time to edit the answer to add the code highlighting but not upvote the question nor the answer?